# in a Eclipse view shortcut binding key does work for some operation but does not operate for others

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

We have a view that we developed, in this view at the beginning a keyboard shortcut key binding works. So I open a list. Then After right clicking the opened list item, I get the context menu. Now after getting this last context menu, I try to hide the list by clicking the same key binding. But the windows computer gives a sound of bing. It sounds like a focus lost but nope, The list item is higlighted. And when I press the item and then press the key binging it bings again. And interestingly the other keys does work. I can press other key options and they work but the shortcut key binding key that hides and shows the list of items does not work.  When I right click to the item that does not work with certain key bindings, does work interestingly. any idea about this situation ?

Comment: When I press the key before opening sub items context menu. execute method of the handler does not called ? Any idea, After right clicking the item, and after the context menu is shown, then pressing the key makes the execute method called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We  have used setEnabled in code, that disables the shortcuts. After deleting these enablement code we got the keys work as we want.